# Parameter is not valid. Error when at memorystream line of my code. I inserted the file as jpeg and i dont know why it fails

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I'm trying to retrieve an image from my ms access database using a listbox(listers). When i inserted my image with another form (converted to long binary data) i didn't have any problems but now that i'm trying to retrieve it. I get the error "Parameter is not valid"

```
    using (conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                using (cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT PICTURE FROM HomeBased WHERE ID = @id", conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", listers.SelectedValue);
                    conn.Open();
                    byte[] bytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    conn.Close();
                    picmid.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bytes));
                }
            }
```

anyways here is my code, if there's anything wrong with it. please help me.

another info: it works fine when i try to retrieve pic from a different table but with that table i can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Can you show what you saved to the database and how? Have you opened and modified some fields in Access?

Comment: AFAIK, parameters for Acc are `?`. your SQL should be: `"SELECT PICTURE FROM HomeBased WHERE ID = ?`

Comment: @marlan  No, it's ok. MS Access uses positional parameters. You can give them whatever name you want (both in `SELECT` and `INSERT`), they just need to be in the correct sequence.